# Encryption in Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I have an array of 10 random numbers generated by code. Is there any way that i can encrypt the array with a public key and only the user with the corresponding private key can decode and decrypt the array.

Comment: Use any asymmetric key algorithm to generate public private key pair on both server and android side, and use user's device imei number to generate public private key pair.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate :D,  So for the server side i will take the imei of the user during registration, use that imei to generate keypairs, store the public key in the database ?

Comment: yep, you can store the public key in database and use that key to encrypt the keyboard layout.

Comment: how do i generate a key from the imei? Im aware of KeyGenerator but im unable to figure out how to generate key that depends on the imei, i want to generate same key for same imei, consider symmetric aes keys for now

Comment: added an answer..please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate Secret Key using mobile's IMEI number

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec("KeyOfSize16Leng.".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, spec);
```

> Secret Parameter required is of size 16 characters, so take substring of IMEI Number from 0 to 16 characters or if it is less than 16 characters then add any known character to the end till length becomes 16.

Perform this step in server side and in android side.

Hope it'll help.